# Pythonic Way to Serialize Query Results with non-standard types to JSON

Tags: python, json, web-services, sqlalchemy

So I am learning how to build a flask webservice and I started off with some code like this.

```
#...
class Objects(Resource) :
    def get(self) :
        conn = engine.connect()
        query = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM objects")
        return {'objects' : [dict(zip(tuple(query.keys()), i)) for i in query.cursor]}

api.add_resource(objects, '/objects')`
#...
```

which was fine until I came across a table with a field in the database represented as a decimal which was not serializable with the above example.

So I fumbled around and came up with the following.

```
class object(Resource) :
    def get(self):
        conn = engine.connect()
        query = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM objects")
        objects = []
        for row in query:
            object = {}
            for key in query.keys() :
                if(type(row[key]) is decimal.Decimal) :
                    object[key] = float(row[key])
                else :
                    object[key] = row[key]
            objects.append(object)       

        return {'objects': objects}
```

That code works fine but my gut is telling me there must be a better way to write it. Being new to python however I am not sure how to proceed...

How would one deal with the above case in a more pythonic way taking advantage of pythons features and class libraries?

Comment: use dict comprehensions. But most of all use http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead of this site.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the codereview.stackexchange.com site I will use it in future for this type of question.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsonpickle.github.io/ is a decent library for serializing Python objects into JSON strings.

```
import jsonpickle
json_str = jsonpickle.encode(obj)
```

There is also a method to decode it later on.

If you ever serialize SQLAlchemy model instances (vs. SQL result sets), make sure you either detach or make them transient though to avoid issues.